# How to check whether two ints are have a difference of 2?

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

Given int x, I want to be able to check if it has increased or decreased by 2. Is there a clean way to do this using the +- condition or should I check both if increased and if decreased separately using or?

Is it possible to make the if statement shorter or do I just have to check multiple conditions at once instead of both at the same time using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by storing initial value of variable and then comparing it with actual using [`Math.Abs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=net-7.0) method

```
var initialX = x; // store value of x before modification

// operations on x

if (Math.Abs(initialX - x) == 2)
{
    // x was decreased or increased by 2
}
```

As long as `x` is value type, it would be convenient to wrap up operations in separate method and use it like this:

```
if (Math.Abs(PerformOperations(x) - x) == 2)
{
    // x was decreased or increased by 2
}
```

But `PerformOperations` can't take params as reference (with `ref` keyword).

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful -  would this same method work for other numbers?

Comment: @Dalton Yes : )

Comment: @Dalton - No. It will work for any of the integer types and `decimal`. It will not work (reliably) for `float` and `double`.

Comment: It also works reliable for float and double WITHIN THEIR DEFINITION - which is that you compare to value X + defined (read from their struct) Epsilon. Epsilon is should be part of every floating operation and is part of their standard - it also is part of the knowledge programmers generally seem to be ignorant about.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it using `||` operator, something like this, here `prevX` is previous value.

```
if (x - prevX == 2 || prevX - x == 2) {
  
}
```